# Swift firebase get data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get `name, quant` from this structure:

[image]

Im try this:

```
var handle: DatabaseHandle?
var ref: DatabaseReference?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     ref = Database.database().reference()
     handle = ref?.child("Цитаты").child("Из Книг").child("Дорогой звезд").child("Quote1").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
     let user = snapshot.value
        print(user!) //text from name + 10 + Quote1
    }
```

When I print `snapshot.value` it's give me data from `Quote1` , but I want to show name in textField and quant in label I try this:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
handle = ref?.child("Цитаты").child("Из Книг").child("Дорогой звезд").child("Quote1").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
let user = snapshot.value
if let us = user!["name"] as? String {
  if let quant = user!["quant"] as? String{
    self.quoteTextField.text = us
    self.quotelabel.text = quant
  }
}
```

And have error. How can I add data from snapshot.value to label and textField?

Comment: Can you add your error to the question?

Comment: @ChrisEdgington , `Type 'Any' has no subscript members`  in `if let us = user!["name"] as? String {`

Answer (score 1):

As I was checking your screen, quant is an Int not String, so try this

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
handle = ref?.child("Цитаты").child("Из Книг").child("Дорогой звезд").child("Quote1").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
       //let username = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       let user = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
       if let us = user!["name"] as? String {
            if let quant = user!["quant"] as? Int {
                 self.quoteTextField.text = us
                 self.quotelabel.text = quant.description
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I have error - `Type 'Any' has no subscript members` in `if let us = user!["name"] as? String {`

Comment: Change your user declaration to `let user = snapshot.value as [String: Any]`. This will cast your value to [String: Any]. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `snapshot.value` as a dictionary -

`let user = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary`

You should also consider safely unwrapping your optionals -

```
let name = user?["name"] as? String ?? ""
let quant = user?["quant"] as? Int ?? 0
```